# My App's functionality is severely impacted after upgrading from JQuery-UI 1.8rc3 to 1.8.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I upgraded our JQuery-UI from 1.8rc3 to 1.8.6 and now I am having major issues creating what we call a step object.

Before I upgraded, if you added a step, this is what the user saw:

[image]

After making a selection from the select list (say "enter text"), the step automagically changed to this:

[image]

Now, however, after upgrading, if I try to create a step and select something from the select list, it does not change. Instead, it just looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how upgrading JQuery-UI could've caused this? I suppose I could just add the 1.8.6 files one-by-one into my app to find out what exactly is causing this, but that will be extremely time-consuming, obviously. Thanks!

Here is the code that generates the step:

```
%li.step.new_step.inline_edit{ :id => dom_id(step), :class => 'template step_template'}

  - form_for [container, step], :html => {:class => 'edit_step editing_only show_progress'} do |f|
    = f.hidden_field :insertion_point

    .action_selector
      = f.text_field :action_description, :maxlength => 255, 'data-help-id' => 'action_description', :placeholder => 'Choose an action...'
      = image_tag 'disclosure_triangle_open.gif', :class => 'autocomplete_triangle'

    .step_types
      - Step.strategy_classes.each do |strategy_class|
        = fields_for_step_type(strategy_class, f)
    .submit
      %button.save_continue.default_action{ :type => 'submit', :id => 'element_savecontinue' } Save and Continue
      %button.save_step_close{ :class => 'button gray save_close', :type => 'button', :id => 'element_save' } Save and Close
      %button.cancel_edit{ :type => 'button',:id => 'element_cancel' } Cancel
      %button.reset_new_step_type{ :type => 'reset', :id => 'reset_step' } Reset
```

Comment: Where's the code that this is using? I don't see any jQueryUI specific widgets here, except for button perhaps...

Comment: I will edit my original question and insert the code.

Comment: can you link to your app? seeing your rails code doesn't really help, we would need to see your jquery code, ideally in action.

Comment: OK, I've narrowed the cause down to one file: jquery-ui.autocomplete.js. I don't know what happened between 1.8rc3 and 1.8.6, but I will continue to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if I continue to use my original jquery-ui.autocomplete.js file but upgrade every single other jquery-ui.***.js file, everything works and looks great. Accepting.